# how to connect Google openid claimed_id with oauth2 user id

Tags: openid, userinfo

Google openid returns a claimed_id, such as https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=Apt0atlGwaRLf6bidtlCtqFNpp1Rvdg0Ka8aqrs

And Google oauth2 userinfo returns a number is, 100168242610783512505.

Given one, how to get the other one? I want to nomalize openid and oauth2 login process. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just found it.  Hope this helps.

[Adjust the OAuth2 request that you send to Google](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-federated-login-api/dNvMHuzUTAU/W-bPbZ2omlAJ)